# ¿Cómo puedo cargar archivos CSS y JS en Django?

Tags: python, django

No he podido enlazar mis archivos CSS y JS a mi HTML utilizando Django 1.11. Esto es lo que tengo:

En el **settings.py** tengo lo siguiente:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

en el **.HTML** tengo:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    ....
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/misEstilos.css' %}">
    ....
</html>
```

En el **urls.py** esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    url(r'^$', views.home)              
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

y en **views.py** tengo:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'principal.html', {})
```

No se que tengo mal. Gracias por su ayuda.

---

Ya lo solucioné, pero me queda una duda. Qué diferencia hay entre:

```
{% load static %}
```

y

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: Si tienes otra pregunta puedes realizarla haciendo referencia a esta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema que tienes es tienes el nombre de la carpeta diferente en los settings a como la estas llamando en el template, deberias cambiar alguna de ellas para que funciona o de la manera que tiene el nombre la carpeta que has creado para almacenar los estaticos.

Cambia lo siguiente y prueba de nuevo
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

Pero asegurate de que tu carpeta tenga ese mismo nombre

Comment: Gracias @ikenshu no es el `STATIC_ROOT` no se porque el problema está en el load.