# Cómo cambiar los colores de django-admin

Tags: css, django, django-admin

Estoy creando una aplicación web con Django. Me gustaría saber cómo cambiar los colores que proporciona django-admin.

Comment: consulta quieres usar tu css o quieres saber donde esta el css que trae por defecto?

Comment: Si tienes las dos opciones sería grandioso, pero solo necesito una respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder utilizar css personalizado tienes que crear la carpeta de static y tener la estructura parecida a esta

```
 djangoPrueba
├── blog
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
└── mysite
```

Y en la carpeta static es donde estara el css.
Te tendria que quedar algo asi:

`blog/static/css/blog.css`

Si tienes problemas de permisos para acceder al `css` esta la solución [Permisos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100447/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-cargar-archivos-css-y-js-en-django)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, y en el caso del css que trae django por defecto, dónded está?

Comment: En static/template solo que es cuando tienes un template segun estaba viendo la documentación oficial [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: de nada :) espero te sirva